# postgres how to add a variable inside a with statement?

Tags: postgresql, common-table-expression

the are a way to add a text variable inside the With statement?

```
sSQL = 'insert into countries values(DEFAULT,''Chile'') RETURNING  id'      ;   
WITH rows AS(
   sSQL
) SELECT id INTO _id FROM rows;
```

Comment: Not sure what you want to do, but probably not.

Comment: You mean inside a function? If so yes. Search for dynamic SQL

Comment: i just like to insert into the "WITH" command a variable, at first the "With" command just accepts only direct SQL commands.